# Should we make this question Canonical-QA?

Tags: discussion

I saw a duplicate today asking:

> Why doesn't the following work?
>
> ```
> SObject record; // assigned elsewhere
> if (record.Some_Checkbox__c) { ... }
> ```

It took me a little while to find a good Q&A, even though I knew I had seen similar before, and even posted the accepted answer.

[Working with SObjects instead of concrete custom objects (i.e., abstraction in apex)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/173162/2995)

Should we mark this post as canonical? Should the question and/or answer be a wiki? Our community consensus/guidance in this area seems unclear.

Comment: I'm in support of tagging as a canonical QA. Questions about `get()`/`put()` as well as static field access with `SObject` are pretty common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. Going with yes, this Q&A is canonical.